# Yii2 rules work only use scenario

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, scenarios

I write two scenario in Yii2 comment model, when user logged on or is guest.

my rules is:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_USER],
            [['name', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_GUEST],
            [['post_id', 'body', 'date'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'parent_id', 'post_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['body'], 'string'],
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'email', 'site'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
        ];
    }
```

and senarios funtion :

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_GUEST] = ['name' , 'email'];
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_USER] = ['user_id'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
$commentModel = Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? new Comment(['scenario' => Comment::SCENARIO_GUEST]) : new Comment(['scenario' => Comment::SCENARIO_USER]);
```

if guest view form, only name and email checked and user fill form, no field checked !
why other rules don't check? how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer [Yii2 Scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models)

The scenarios() method returns an array whose keys are the scenario names and values the corresponding active attributes. An active attribute can be massively assigned and is subject to validation.

```
public function scenarios()
{
     $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
     $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_GUEST] = ['name' , 'email', 'date', 'body', 'site', 'post_id'];
     $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_USER] = ['user_id', 'date', 'body', 'site', 'post_id'];
     return $scenarios;
}
```

Comment: An additional tip, if you got over 5 attributes, you can get all the attributes and only remove the matching ones. Say you want to exclude an attribute in a particular scenario, instead of listing 10 attributes in order to exclude a single one, you could `array_diff(array_flip($this->attributes), ['excludedAttribute1', 'excludedAttribute2'])`, I'm on my phone, but I think you need to flip $this->attributes due to key holding attribute name and value holding attribute value, no matter if the model's attributes have been assigned a value or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`scenarios()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#scenarios()-detail) you need to define all attributes allowed to assign in given scenario. So if you want to allow guest to edit also `body` and `date` you need something like:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_GUEST] = ['name' , 'email', 'body', 'date'];
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_USER] = ['user_id'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

If you have many "shared" attributes between scenarios, you probably should not override this method and define it in `rules()` only.

See more in [scenarios documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios).